# PHP send mail to multiple email addresses

Tags: php, forms

What code I should do change in this PHP script to send **one email to more than 20 email addresses**?

```
<?php

$email_to = "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com"; // your email address
$email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; // email subject line
$thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; // thank you page

?>
```

Please give me an example. Thank you.

Comment: It's unfortunate that no one reads the manual anymore.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the manual

Comment: Manuals and documentations are useful and relevant for in-depth research. But Googling and StackOverflowing is often faster if you need the answer to a specific but common use case; especially if it can be presented in the size of a tweet or single monitor height. I wish manuals would be so flexible as to provide both.

Comment: @AlecSmart: It's also unfortunate that so many manuals are so poorly written as to be nearly unusable.

Answer (score 62):

Fore readability sake in the code use an array and implode it to a comma separated string:-

```
$recipients = array(
  "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
  // more emails
);
$email_to = implode(',', $recipients); // your email address
$email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; // email subject line
$thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; // thank you page
```

Comment: Please never do it like that, if the recipients do not (or should not) know each other. This way every address is exposed to every recipient.

Answer (score 43):

Your

```
$email_to = "address@one.com, address@two.com, address@three.com"
```

Needs to be a comma delimited list of email adrresses.

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $thankyou);
```

Comment: why do you put a space after the comma? and not .com,address for example?

Comment: @Jon, I'd propose the spaces after the commas help with readability

Answer (score 30):

Just separate them by comma, like `$email_to = "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com, emailtwo@yourdomain.com, John Doe <emailthree@example.com>"`.

Answer (score 14):

Following code will do the task....

```
<?php

$contacts = array(
"youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
"youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
//....as many email address as you need
);

foreach($contacts as $contact) {

$to      =  $contact;
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

?>
```

Comment: be aware that you have not include the var for the $headers and also if you put that in the loop it will several times in each mail.

Comment: Unlike the previous responses that send one email to a group, this suggestion will send multiple emails, one to each recipient. Given the ambiguity of the original request, either response could be correct. Note that as @Paul Spiegel pointed out, it is bad form to send group emails in the To field. BCC is preferred.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
mail("john@doe.com , marry@mail.com , frank@domain.com", "Test e-mail", "Hi, this is a test message!");
```

http://myphpform.com/php-form-multiple-recipients.php

Answer (score 5):

It is very bad practice to send all email addresses to all recipients; you should use Bcc (blind carbon copies).

```
    $from = "myname@mymail.com";
    $recipList = "mailaddress1,mailaddress2,etc";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nFrom: {$from}\nBcc: {$recipList}\nDate: ".date(DATE_RFC2822);
    mail(null,$subject,$message,$headers); //send the eail
```

Comment: Bcc does not really hide anything from anyone. All you need to do is look at the headers and you still know all the email addresses

Answer (score 5):

```
    $recipients = "test1@test.com,test2@test.com,test3@test.com,test1@test.com";
    $email_array = explode(",",$recipients);
    foreach($email_array as $email)
    {
        echo $to      =  $email;
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = 'hello';
       $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way could be to save all the emails in a database.

You can try this code, assuming you have your email in a database

```
/*Your connection to your database comes here*/
$query="select email from yourtable";
$result =mysql_query($query);
```

/*the above code depends on where you saved your email addresses, so make sure you replace it with your parameters*/

Then you can make a comma separated string from the result,

```
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
        if($rows=='')    //this prevents from inserting comma on before the first element
        $rows.=$row['email'];
        else
        $rows.=','.$row['email'];
    }
```

Now you can use

```
$to = explode(',',$rows); // to change to array

$string =implode(',',$cc); //to get back the string separated by comma
```

With above code you can send the email like this

```
mail($string, "Test", "Hi, Happy X-Mas and New Year");
```

Comment: why you you not jsut put the fecthed emails directly into an array and then `implode` just before you call `mail`?

Comment: Yes, That is correct. I am doing same thing twice to show what is going on with in explode()

Answer (score 1):

In mail function you can as many reciepient as you want in $emailto paramater seperated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
$to = $email1 .','. $email2 .','. $email3;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
$recipient_email = 'sales@abc.com,support@xyz.com';

$success = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write multiple email address to whom you want to send and pass it as the first argument.
Example:-

```
mail("FirstEmailId@ABC.com, SecondEmilId@XYZ.com","Subject","Message","From: EmailId@PQR.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will works.

```
$tos = array('address1@yourdomain.com', 'address2@yourdomain.com');
foreach ($tos as $to){
    $ok = mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from);
}
if ($ok) {
    echo "Message Send";
} else { 
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this example sends the many copies of the same email... rather than the same email to many recipients.

Comment: In this way only the last mail is checked in the `if`. You should put the `if..else` blocks in the loop