# Mail Multiple users with php

Tags: php, email

I normally mail single user on php but what I dont know if its possible to fetch all emails from the users table and bundle it in one variable (`$to`) and then mail it together with

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax on how to mail multiple users? I am new to php and mysqli. 
Thanks.

Comment: Example #4: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You can try yourself : )) But that's not advisable, rely on some queue /existing service like Mailchimp for instance.

Comment: It depends on your specific use case, but I'd generally advise against this as well, for two reasons: 1) Most mail servers limit the number of recipients that you can send to with a single message. 2) If you send a message in this manner, each recipient will be able to see the email addresses of all the other recipients.

Comment: Nice taught alex. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[PHP send mail to multiple email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506078/php-send-mail-to-multiple-email-addresses)

```
$recipients = array(
  "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
  // more emails
);

$email_to = implode(',', $recipients); // your email address
$email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; // email subject line
$thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; // thank you page

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $thankyou);
```

Note that you can use a custom message in place of `$thankyou` if you just want a standard message instead of html.