# Does my $to variable have to link in this situation

Tags: php, variables

Does my `$to` variable have to equals something in this situation or will my functions fill that in automatically.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
    $to = "test@test.com";
}
if (isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
    $to = "test@test.com";
}
if (isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
    $to = "test@test.com";
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $MainCB = $_POST['MainCB'];
    $ITCB = $_POST['ITCB'];
    $CateCB = $_POST['CateCB'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $full_name . " " . $MainCB . " " . $ITCB . " " . $CateCB;
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
    include 'mail.php';
}
?>
```

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="LOGS">LOGS</h1>
        <h1 id="FormTitle">Event Request Form</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table id="Table">
                <tr id="FullName"><td>Full Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="full_name"></td></tr>
                <tr id="EventT"><td>Event Title:</td> <td><input type="text" name="EventT"></td></tr>
                <tr id="Department"><td>Person/Dept in Charge:</td> <td><input type="text" name="InCharge"></td></tr>
                <tr id="Venue"><td>Venue:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Venue"></td><tr>
                <tr id="Ven"><td>Have you checked venue availability:</td> <td>Yes <input type="checkbox" name ="VenY">No <input type="checkbox" id="VenN" name ="VenN"></td><tr>
                <tr id="Adults"><td>No. of Adults:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Adults"></td><tr>
                <tr id="Children"><td>No. of Children:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Children"></td><tr>
                <tr id="MainCB"><td>Maintenance:</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name ="MainCB"></td><tr>
                <tr id="ITCB"><td>IT:</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="ITCB"></td><tr>
                <tr id="CateCB"><td>Catering:</td>  <td><input type="checkbox" name="CateCB"></td><tr>
                <tr id="CatReq"><td>Catering Requirments:</td></tr>
                <tr><td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="CatReq"></textarea></td><tr>
                <tr id="LogReq"><td>Logistical Requirements/Equipment:</td></tr> 
                <tr><td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="LogReq"></textarea></td><tr>
                <tr id="ITReq"><td>IT Requirements:</td></tr> 
                <tr><td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="ITReq"></textarea></td><tr>
                <tr id="Trans"><td>Transport Booked:</td> <td>Yes <input type="checkbox" name ="TransY"> No <input type="checkbox" name ="TransN"></td><tr> 
                <tr id="Email"><td>Email:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Email"></td><tr>
                <tr id="EXT"><td>EXT:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Ext"></td><tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbutton">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php  
    $recipients = array();

    if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
        $recipients[] = "test@test.com"// one address email; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
        $recipients[] = "test2@test.com"// one other address email; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
        $recipients[] = "test3@test.com"// one more address email; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($recipients) ){ // You need to have at least one email address to send it
        $to = implode(',', $recipients); // All your email address
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
        $MainCB = $_POST['MainCB'];
        $ITCB = $_POST['ITCB'];
        $CateCB = $_POST['CateCB'];
        $subject = "Form submission";
        $message = $full_name . " " . $MainCB . " " . $ITCB . " " . $CateCB;
        mail($to,$subject,$message);
        include 'mail.php';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You cannot send an email without telling it where it should be sent TO

Comment: remove line -         $to = "";

Comment: I also doubt you have a field on your form with the attribute `name` set to `name='test@test.com'` so whats `$to = $_POST["test@test.com"];` all about

Comment: Do my top functions not fill that in? as they fill the $to function when they are checked

Comment: Yes, then the `$to = "";` destroys whatever you did before

Comment: Well, the ways you build it you should use `else if` because if you have `isset($_POST["MainCB"])` and `isset($_POST['submit'])` both true for example, you will have `$to = "";`

Comment: sorry the isset checks, and they check to see if a check box is checked then I want them to fill out the $to variable with the test@test.com email if they are checked

Comment: I want it to send to multiple email addresses if more then one are ticked

Comment: So that should be `$to = "test@test.com";`

Comment: So would this work?

Comment: The above code? No!

Comment: I dont get why :/

Comment: Also, Please dont change your question code, add a new version if you like, but if you chnage stuuf it makes all the comments and maybe answers look like nonsense

Comment: @RyanDownes You're just overwriting the same variable every time - if you're expecting anything else then the issue is with understanding how PHP variables work, rather than anything to do with sending emails

Comment: Sorry, im new to this :/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to read some documentation on how to do posts in PHP, besides that what are you trying to accomplish?

```
if(isset($_POST["MainCB"]) || isset($_POST["ITCB"]) || isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
  $to = "test@test.com"; 
}
```

Will do the same thing, further more `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` should always equal true, in fact this should be your most outer if else statement. Then you're rewriting the `$to` variable with with `''` so remove that other wise the code before it has no use-case.

Code is logic, read the code understand it and adjust your if else statements where needed.

```
if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])){
  $to[] = 'mycustomemail@address.com';
}

if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])){
  $to[] = 'mycustomemail2@address.com';
}

if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])){
  $to[] = 'mycustomemail3@address.com';
}

if(!empty($to)){
  $to = array_unique($to); // remove duplicate entry's.
  foreach($to as $address){
    if(!filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      die("'$address' is not a valid email");
    }
  }
  $to = implode(", ", $to);
} else {
  die('No addresses to send the mail to!');
}
```

Now `$to` will have all the addresses wanted in 1 string to be used in `mail()` however should think about using a library such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), but first focus on the basics of programming.

Comment: Except I am thinking he wants to send to 3 different addresses based on those IF's and not the same one

Comment: That is true Riggs

Comment: I dont need to pipe in this situation

Comment: Oops haha I suck at this, slowly getting it though! I think, I believe @Mickael Leger has the right answer, will check this out and get back to you guys

Comment: I have updated the code appropriately, but I really recommend you reading a tutorial or 2 on how to properly handle form posting.

Comment: The isset will always have an email attached to them, you would never need to kill if blank email address, unless unchecked? im guessing

Comment: @RyanDownes That fully depends on the html form, which seems to be missing in the question. If the name `MainCB` is a checkbox with no value, it only shows weather the box is checked or not, no value. If its a `text input`, it should contain the given string.

Comment: I have now added the form

Comment: With the new edit you did, will I still need the last part of my code which sends the email?

Comment: Yes. I am not providing a copy paste-able code. How else would you learn? Read the code, follow the logic and adjust where necessary. I only made sure the code provided handles your question. Your edit seems to do the job, I'm just not sure what you want to say in the `$message` variable.

Comment: I found a way to do what I wanted sorry for wording the question wrong I guess

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said in the comment and this question : [PHP send mail to multiple email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506078/php-send-mail-to-multiple-email-addresses)

You can try somehting like this to have multiple "to":

```
<?php  

$recipients = array();

if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
    $recipients[] = // one address email; 
}
if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
    $recipients[] = // one other address email; 
}
if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
    $recipients[] = // one more address email; 
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($recipients) ){ // You need to have at least one email address to sent it
    $to = implode(',', $recipients); // All your email address
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $MainCB = $_POST['MainCB'];
    $ITCB = $_POST['ITCB'];
    $CateCB = $_POST['CateCB'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $full_name . " " . $MainCB . " " . $ITCB . " " . $CateCB;
    mail($to,$subject,$message);
    include 'mail.php';
}
?>
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Could you explain what the implode part does?

Comment: " Join array elements with a string" (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php). So you will have address1, address2, ...

Comment: I think so, I need to send the form to different email addresses depending on what the checkbox is

Comment: this could be one of them or multiple

Comment: The idea is that you need to build your "to" according to the data you get and where you need to send your email. So you make a test, if test is true -> add the email, second test false -> don't add it, third test true -> add it, etc. And at the end you send email to all the people you need according to your test. Is it clear enought?

Comment: Hope you will solve your problem, tell me if it works !

Comment: Hi Mickael, I have uploaded the form and your PHP advice, did I lay it out correctly or am I doing this all wrong

Comment: I'm thinking of adding a checkbox for people who don't need those departments this will solve the issue of no email

Comment: Try it to know it ! You need multiple adresse email to test if it works so

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\NewTest\mail.php on line 6

Comment: I don't have a missing bracket? this is confusing

Comment: Your forgot the `;` after your email address no?

Comment: That was the problem but this code didnt work, I found out the correct way of doing things, I guess I worded my question wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
    $email = $email.  ", example@logs.uk.com";
}
if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
    $email = $email. ", example@logs.uk.com";
}
if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
    $email = $email. ", example@logs.uk.com";
}
$mail = $_POST["Email"];
```

Comment: It will be better if you add some description

Comment: @RyanDownes instead of commenting "this is correct", wait until your answer is acceptable, check if there's any more useful/detailed answer and accept the most useful one. As for your answer, please comment it so that it's clear what the problem was and how you solved it: this way, the Q&A you created will be helpful for others. Best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I was told to read a book on PHP for the answer but this just adds an email to the variable email when it is selected, and wont overwrite like all the other answers! So if you need to send to multiple Mail boxes depending on Check boxes then this will do it